# Activation script hangs and cannot shutdown

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have implemented SQL Server Service Broker with error handling according to [this](http://rusanu.com/2007/10/31/error-handling-in-service-broker-procedures/) article by Remus Resanu.

When I ran the process and the activation script got kicked off but never stopped processing.   According to the SQL Server log file it looks like I have a typo in my error handling and it is now stuck in an infinite loop.

I have tried to kill the process using `kill <pid>` but I get the message `Only user processes can be killed`.  I have also tried restarting the server but the activation script would start again.

How do I kill the runaway activation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution through google/bing search. I eventually remembered that we enabled the Service broker through a SQL command, so I tried disabling it and that seems to have worked:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET DISABLE_BROKER;
```

Comment: You may need to append "with rollback immediate" to kill off dependent transactions

Answer (score 1):

It looks like undocumented feature. If activated procedure do not issue END CONVERSATION it keeps restarting in an infinite loop. So, to stop it you need to make it successfully run END CONVERSATION of any dialog. If the queue gets disabled due to poison message detection you need to drop it to stop activation proc - no need to reset broker. I did not found either solution to this problem out there so I played with it a bit and hope this gives you a hint.